# Load Json data into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

```
list = {'masterId': 2, 'name': 'name', 'description': 'xyz', 'signalTypeRefId': 4, 'unitOfMeasureRefId': 1, 'precision': 1, 'min': -125, 'max': 125, 'isDeprecated': False}
```

I need the above json loaded into a dataframe and tried the following but doesn't work

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list, orient = 'index')
display(df)
```

Error:

> TypeError: field 0: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>

Comment: Please do not overwrite the built `list`! Try to name your variable differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the dictionary into a list before creating the dataframe:

```
data = {'masterId': 2, 'name': 'name', 'description': 'xyz', 'signalTypeRefId': 4, 'unitOfMeasureRefId': 1, 'precision': 1, 'min': -125, 'max': 125, 'isDeprecated': False}

df = spark.createDataFrame([data])

df.show()
+-----------+------------+--------+---+----+----+---------+---------------+------------------+
|description|isDeprecated|masterId|max| min|name|precision|signalTypeRefId|unitOfMeasureRefId|
+-----------+------------+--------+---+----+----+---------+---------------+------------------+
|        xyz|       false|       2|125|-125|name|        1|              4|                 1|
+-----------+------------+--------+---+----+----+---------+---------------+------------------+
```

Or you can convert it to a pandas dataframe and create a Spark dataframe from that, though you still need to wrap the dictionary into a list:

```
data = {'masterId': 2, 'name': 'name', 'description': 'xyz', 'signalTypeRefId': 4, 'unitOfMeasureRefId': 1, 'precision': 1, 'min': -125, 'max': 125, 'isDeprecated': False}

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([data]))

df.show()
+--------+----+-----------+---------------+------------------+---------+----+---+------------+
|masterId|name|description|signalTypeRefId|unitOfMeasureRefId|precision| min|max|isDeprecated|
+--------+----+-----------+---------------+------------------+---------+----+---+------------+
|       2|name|        xyz|              4|                 1|        1|-125|125|       false|
+--------+----+-----------+---------------+------------------+---------+----+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = pd.DataFrame([list])
```

For more info converting JSON to pandas DataFrames please check out link below :)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
dct = {'masterId': 2, 'name': 'name', 'description': 'xyz', 'signalTypeRefId': 4, 'unitOfMeasureRefId': 1, 'precision': 1, 'min': -125, 'max': 125, 'isDeprecated': False}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient="index")
display(df)

"""
                        0
masterId                2
name                 name
description           xyz
signalTypeRefId         4
unitOfMeasureRefId      1
precision               1
min                  -125
max                   125
isDeprecated        False
"""
```

To have it as a row, use `.transpose()`

```
df.transpose()
"""
Out[15]: 
  masterId  name description     ...        min  max isDeprecated
0        2  name         xyz     ...       -125  125        False
"""
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:300: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  an integer is required (got type str)
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warnings.warn(msg)
TypeError: field 0: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>

Comment: I don't have spark installed. Some strange interference between packages it seems ...

Comment: maybe if you have conda, create a new conda environment, install there python and then pandas only and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.json_normalize(list)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html